# How to notify TabCtrl when its parent window closes?

Tags: mfc, win32gui

I'm using BCG Pro's control `CBCGPTabWnd`, which contains multiple tab windows, when the parent Dialog's `OnOK()` is called, I don't know how to notify the tab windows for cleanup and save work.

And I cannot add public interfaces for those tab windows to call to do this.

Now I'm using `TabWnd->SendMessage(WM_COMMAND, IDOK)` in the parent's `OnOK` handler to stimulate the OnOK Message for those child tab windows, because they are actually dialog-based windows.

Am I doing this right?

PS: Generally it would be better if I can notify them explicitly, WM_DESTROY is an option but it can only be used in Closing and is hard to control the timing

Comment: Why don't you handle WM_DESTROY? The child Windows will at least receive this Messages when the parent is destroyed. Also you have WM_PARENTNOTIFY where the parent is informed about the destruction of a child.

Comment: Thanks. I have considered this. But it would be better if there is a more explicit way because sometimes I want the tab windows to save work in other situations than closing. So what else I can do is to define my custom message?

Comment: Add a WM_APP+n message and send it to all descendants.

Comment: @xMRi OK...If you make it an answer, I can vote up

Answer (score 1):

Just send a private/cursom message internally with WM_APP+n.
Handle it with ON_MESSAGE.

This makes it possible to react on every case were your parent needs to inform the embedded child windows. And you can implement it in different window types.